# Date index is not monotonic in ARIMA prediction model

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime, arima

I want to start by saying that I'm new to python and to programming in general, so please let me know if I missed out any important information to this question.

I'm currently working on using the ARIMA model for time series analysis.
The dataframe I'm using consists of one column of float data and the index which is in datetime format.
This is how I loaded the data:

```
df = pd.read_csv('L_strom_30974_gerundet.csv', sep=';', names=['Timestamp', 'Mean'])
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Timestamp,format= '%d.%m.%y %H:%M', infer_datetime_format=True)
df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index).to_period('15T')
```

This is the Header of the dataframe:

```
                  Mean
Timestamp             
2009-01-01 00:00  36.0
2009-01-01 00:15  34.0
2009-01-01 00:30  34.0
2009-01-01 00:45  34.0
2009-01-01 01:00  34.0
```

And this is the info of the dataframe:

```
PeriodIndex: 61628 entries, 2009-01-01 00:00 to 2010-04-10 23:45
Freq: 15T
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------  --------------  -----  
 0   Mean    61628 non-null  float64
dtypes: float64(1)
```

When I'm trying to train the model, I get an error message:

```
model=ARIMA(train['Mean'],order=(1,1,2))
model=model.fit()
model.summary()
```

-->**ValueWarning: A date index has been provided, but it is not monotonic and so will be ignored when e.g. forecasting.** self._init_dates(dates, freq)

I looked this problem up an and people proposed to convert the data to DateTime index and set a frequency using to_period(), but I tried (see line 3 of code) it and it didn't work.
Related question: [Ordering Timestamps for ARIMA model predicion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62098301/ordering-timestamps-for-arima-model-predicion)

Any idea what's the problem?

Comment: In the linked question, people suggested doing `df = df.sort_index()` to fix a non-monotonic (i.e. unordered) index. Does that work?

Comment: Yes this answers it